# Save images in NSCache after terminating app

Tags: ios, swift, nscache

I'm currently developing an iOS application where I've a lot of images. I use `NSCache()` for storing the images.

So, every time I load the application the images is being downloaded, saved in cache and stays in the cache all the way till I terminate the application.

I'm looking for a solution where the images will be saved even if you terminate the application, just download if the image does NOT exists in the current `NSCache()`.

This one is used in the beginning of the extension:

`let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()`

And then I've an extension with a function like this:

```
extension UIImageView {
func downloadImages(from urlString: NSString){

    //Check for cached images and return out if found
    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString) as? UIImage{
        print("cache?", imageCache)
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    //Retrieve the images from Firebase Storage
    let url = URL(string: urlString as String)

    //Create an URL session
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, err) in
        if let err = err{
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }

        //Continue on background thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //Check if image exists
            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!){

                //Add image to cache
                imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString)

                //Set the image to downloaded image.
                self.image = downloadedImage
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

}

The image cache works until I terminate the application. Is there any way I can save the `NSCache()` even if I terminate the app?

Comment: I think this will work for you -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52259000/7512091

Comment: @emrcftci Thanks, I will check that out.

Comment: You will need to store the images in application's 'Documents Directory' If you want to access the images after the app terminates.

Comment: @emrcftci, that will not help if you kill the app.

Comment: @JanbazAli My idea is to cache the images ONCE, and when I enter the app again after terminating the app should still have the images in the cache, instead of loading it again.

Comment: @Putte, I believe if you check, you will find that the cache is getting emptied even if you put the app into background.